# Why can't the variable.php template be overriden in woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to provide my custom variable.php page to woocommerce, but I don't see any changes on the page when I update the file.

I had **no issues with other template** files.

I have the template file on the path `theme/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php`, and woocommerce support is turned on:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'woocommerce_support' );
function woocommerce_support() {
  add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
}
```

Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

Comment: Could it be a caching issue?

Comment: cache is disabled, other changes are visible instantly.. but there may be other caching mechanism I don't know about

Comment: I'm using `theme/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/single.php` and it's working fine, but I've never tried `variable.php`. Sorry I can't help - the only thing I could think of would be maybe if there's some kind of server-side caching, Cloudflare or another CDN, etc.

Comment: Be sure that `define( 'WC_TEMPLATE_DEBUG_MODE', false );` is set to `false` or remove it from `wp-config.php` file.

Comment: @Shoelaced thanks, what wp and wc version are you using? could you check please if variable.php works for you?